# Event-triggering - Ready, On, Fire

Tags: event-handling, go

I have implemented a kind of thing that does event triggering in Golang. This is open-sourced [here](https://github.com/sadlil/go-trigger/tree/ad5085da39636a638d1eaf58fee7d3971ed4dde3). Review and suggestions appreciated.

First thing I am trying to implement is adding event listeners to a trigger:

```
func (t *trigger) On(event string, task interface{}) error {
    if _, ok := t.functionMap[event]; ok {
        return errors.New("event already defined")
    }
    if reflect.ValueOf(task).Type().Kind() != reflect.Func {
        return errors.New("task is not a function")
    }
    t.mu.Lock()
    defer t.mu.Unlock()
    t.functionMap[event] = task
    return nil
 }
```

So that when Fire is called all the handler chain will be executed:

```
func (t *trigger) Fire(event string, params ...interface{}) ([]reflect.Value, error) {
    f, in, err := t.read(event, params...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    result := f.Call(in)
    return result, nil
 }
```

But the thing is that don't want to maintain a whole param array for all the handlers' method parameters. How can it be done otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Your description of the problem indicates that each event type can have multiple listeners, but the code only implements one listener for each event. Is this intended?

The `params` awkwardness is a "feature" of go....

Because Go is

- statically compiled
- does not have function signature overloading (you can't have multiple functions with the same name, and differentiate them based on the signature)

You cannot avoid having the `param` input arguments to the `Fire` function. This is a "drawback" of Go. When you become more comfortable with the language you avoid constructs like you have, because they are hard to maintain (anything requiring `reflect` is probably a bad idea).

Additionally, your `sync` usage is broken - you need to manage the lock on both the `Fire` call, and the `On` call. Your `On` call is also broken because it has a race condition....

Note that reads on the map also need to be sync'd, not just writes.

So, this code:

> ```
> func (t *trigger) On(event string, task interface{}) error {
>     if _, ok := t.functionMap[event]; ok {
>         return errors.New("event already defined")
>     }
>     if reflect.ValueOf(task).Type().Kind() != reflect.Func {
>         return errors.New("task is not a function")
>     }
>     t.mu.Lock()
>     defer t.mu.Unlock()
>     t.functionMap[event] = task
>     return nil
>  }
> ```

should be:

```
func (t *trigger) On(event string, task interface{}) error {
    // Lock the mutex before reading it.
    t.mu.Lock()
    defer t.mu.Unlock()

    if _, ok := t.functionMap[event]; ok {
        return errors.New("event already defined")
    }
    if reflect.ValueOf(task).Type().Kind() != reflect.Func {
        return errors.New("task is not a function")
    }
    t.functionMap[event] = task
    return nil
 }
```

Additionally, the `Fire` should also have a mutex control (perhaps the `t.read(...)` function has a lock?)

> ```
> func (t *trigger) Fire(event string, params ...interface{}) ([]reflect.Value, error) {
>     f, in, err := t.read(event, params...)
>     if err != nil {
>         return nil, err
>     }
>     result := f.Call(in)
>     return result, nil
>  }
> ```

Comment: yes. `t.read()` has a lock inside it. One more question if i lock inside `On` and unlock it at defer how the `t.functionMap[] = task`  is going to work?

Comment: @sadlil - Your question is ... confusing. The `t.mu.Lock()` should happen before the `t.functionMap[event]` read..... and should stick around to the end of the function call so that the `t.functionMap[event] = task` write is in the same locked block. Your question has made me look at the ordering of the method, and you can put the "is `task` a function" check before the lock because that check does not depend on internal `t` state.